# Point And Figure - implementation

Tags: charts, stock

Hi
Can anyone recommend some open source projects for calculating and plotting [point & figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_and_figure_chart) charts with as many as possible options.

Thx

Comment: What kind of options are you looking for? What kind of output do you want? Your question is pretty open ended.

Comment: I want to have same features as they can be found in Bloomberg trading platform, of course I'm talking only about p&f implementation not all features :)

Comment: You might want to explain what that the Bloomberg trading platform does that make you choose it as an example.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only open source useable implementation I could find is [point and figure](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pointandfigure/). There is also [Financio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/financio/).

I'm not used neither one but since nobody answered yet I just pointed out some alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

You might try the new R-package **rpnf** from http://rpnf.r-forge.r-project.org/.

It is able to produce Point & Figure Charts (with downloaded data from yahoo). Additional it identifies sophisticated Buy and Signals like Double/Triple Top/Bottom, Bullish/Bearish Signal for you. Furthermore it can be used to create Relative Strength Charts as well as Bullish Percent Charts.

**Examples**

A PNG-Plot can be seen [here](http://rpnf.r-forge.r-project.org/sampleplot.png).

```
Point & Figure Plot DAX30 (log) 
--------+-----------------------
 7954.90|                      X
 7648.94|                      X
 7354.75|    X X               X
 7071.88|    XOXO            X X
 6799.88|    XOXO            XOX
 6538.35|    XOXO            XOX
 6286.87|X X XO O          X XOX
 6045.07|XOXOX  OX X       XOXOX
 5812.57|XOXOX  OXOXOX     XOXO 
 5589.01| O O   OXOXOXOX X XOX  
 5374.05|       O O OXOXOXOXOX  
 5167.35|           O OXOXOXO   
 4968.61|             OXO O     
 4777.51|             O         
--------+-----------------------
       Y|22222222222222222222222
       Y|00000000000000000000000
       Y|11111111111111111111111
       Y|00000111111111111111122
        |                       
       M|00000000000000000111100
       M|45678338888889999001147
        |                       
       D|00200130111130122000220
       D|57152512015815527461933
```

Answer (score 3):

The best recommendation that I can give for creating an obscure chart format such as point & figure is to try and create it from the tools provided in [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/). This library allows you to make custom charts, using chained DSL type function calls.  Protovis gives you building blocks like labels, lines, and wedges to create your own custom chart visualization.  They have [numerous examples](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/) to get started and great documentation.

Comment: looks nice, but I need to have my own implementation. Plus I haven't seen any support for real-time updates for those charts.

Comment: Might want to stipulate that in the question then. Worse case scenario you could redraw the chart with the new data depending on the frequency of updates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java library (http://mov.sourceforge.net/api/org/mov/chart/graph/PointAndFigureGraph.html) that draws P&F charts. I've not used it though I do use P&F charts on a daily basis for trading.

> Point and Figure graph. This graph draws a series of characters (X/O) mapping the general movement. A change in column shows a reversal such that price difference met the price scale.

Its not very robust, but then again, if you're writing custom or traditional indicators they wouldn't exist in this class anyways.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Point & Figure is one of the supported chart types in the DataVisualization libraries included in .NET 4 (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` and `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`)

See here for more details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456746(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)